# Determinating the subclass. Polymorphism or instanceof

Tags: java, polymorphism, subclass

Say i have 3 classes. One class which is superclass, and the other two those who inherit from it. If i have an instance of the superclass, and i want to know for which of the two subclasses, this object is instance of.

Which of two methods are considered best practise:
1) use instanceOf or getClass() and compare, or
2) declare an  abstract method on the superclass and implement it on subclasses to get an enum which represents the class.

Comment: What do you need the type for? Best practice is that you code in a way that doesn't require you to consider the actual types of your objects. Assuming you obey the substitution principle, you rarely need it outside of stuff like serialization or debugging.

Comment: If for example i have an abstract class Item which represents a generic item, it is nice to have a way to know which specific item it is, and based on this make specific actions.

Comment: @user59559: Actually, it is not that "nice", which is why you're getting the answers "questioning your motives", so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice in this case is polymporphism. Create an abstract method in the super class. Subclasses will be obliged to provide concrete implementation. No need for instanceof or getClass.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, polymorphism is the better answer. If you have to ask which subclass, then when new subclasses are added, there's the danger of forgetting to add new "if" parts to that question.

Comment: On the other hand, using an enum means you'll still need to update that when new classes are added. And since the superclass is presumably switching on the results, the code will have to be updated anyway.

Comment: Yes, switch on Java enum has many of the benefits of polymorphism, if you can use that technique.

Comment: The point is that neither is ideal. The best practice is to come up with a better design that doesn't require this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should use instanceOf. With the approach of enum you must know before hand that you will be later checking for instance and classes have to be prepared for it. So i would prefer instanceOf.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** It is probably the case that you're trying to use the class object, or class name, in a way which is best avoided; and by avoiding it you would probably make your code cleaner and easier to understand and extend.

**Long(er) Answer:** When writing Object-Oriented software code, specifically Java, the principle of [(Subtype) Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism) is employed heavily. To make it super-simplified in the context of your question: If you have an instance of class A, with class A being extended by B and C, you endeavor to only treat A as a "general" A, using its public methods and members; and if you want something different to be done for B and C, you write a method doSomething() for this action on A's, implemented differently in B and in C by overriding A.doSomething()  (the default implementation for A's).

(As suggested in @EvgeniyDorofeev's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731575/1593077), if there's no default action, you can make your default method be abstract; but then A has to be an abstract class.)

This has several advantages:

- A's code does not need to be familiar with B and C.
- If you later add other classes, say, D extending A and E extending C, you would not need to modify your existing code - just override doSomething() in them.
- You don't need to worry about using getClass() or creating artificial enums for classes... :-)

but it is sometimes also criticized, as part of a more general criticism of Object-Oriented approaches (see, for example, [The Noun Shuffle](http://www.geocities.com/tablizer/oopbad.htm#nounshuffle) at [OOP Oversold](http://www.geocities.com/tablizer/oopbad.htm)).

**PS:** Sometimes you can't avoid using getClass() (say, for preparing a log message containing the class name); OP didn't specify the exact problem s/he is facing, so it's difficult to tell. At any case, do *not* go down the path of writing your own enums for classes; use getClass() (from which you could also get the class name if you really need it). Also, you might find there's a library you can use which takes care of these things for you so you don't have to getClass() at all (that's the case for logging, the example I just gave.)

Answer (score -2):

Usually the best practice is by calling the boolean function instanceOf(), this should work just fine.

Although I myself find your second solution much easier to use, but the first one is considered to be good programming practice.

Comment: instanceof is an operator, not a function